# Order by column distinct

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two columns say time(HH:MM:SS) format and message(String) what i wanted to do was to order using message distinct but since i have time column i still get duplicates
ex

```
time         message
10:00:01     hi
10:00:02     hi
```

the expected query should return

```
time         message
10:00:01     hi
```

or

```
time         message
10:00:02     hi
```

as long as the message is one of them since they are the same

i have tried but this didn't work. is this possible to achieve?

```
select distinct time as time
message as a message
from `table_name`
group by message, time
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understand your question it might need a bit clarification (Not sure what to or means in your question).

Anyway is this SQL what you are looking for:

```
select message as message,
time as time
from `table_name`
group by message 
order by message desc, time desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MIN(time) AS time,
  message
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
GROUP BY message 
-- ORDER BY time
```

You can play with it using sample data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_name` AS (
  SELECT '10:00:01' time, 'hi' message UNION ALL
  SELECT '10:00:02', 'hi'
)
SELECT 
  MIN(time) AS time,
  message
FROM `project.dataset.table_name`
GROUP BY message 
-- ORDER BY time
```

this produces

```sql
Row time        message  
1   10:00:01    hi
```

you can use `MAX` instead of `MIN` to produce below result

```sql
Row time        message  
1   10:00:02    hi
```